# Will using appearance proxy on UILabel get my app rejected because it alters UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uialertview, appstore-approval, uiappearance

I'm hoping to customize all of the fonts in my app, and have been using the `[UILabel appearance]` API so far as it seems like the path of least resistance.
I noticed that this also affects the labels inside of the `UIAlertView` (as expected), but I'm also aware that customizing the alert view may cause an app to get rejected.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Should I just make my own subclass of `UILabel` instead and apply it manually to each label in my app?

Comment: I guess that would not be your problem if the system customises the alert view's labels according to the appearance's details. you are using public APIs, that is a side-effect only, even if it was part of your goal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel class conforms to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol, a check of UILabel.h shows that none of its properties are marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR, the prerequisite for the use of UIAppearance. So you need to create UILabel subclass as shown below.

```
@interface SmallLabel : UILabel

@end

@implementation SmallLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
}
  return self;
}
```

@end

I think you can  alsotry in your subclass something like:

```
UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:self.font.pointSize];
self.font = newFont
```